# Is it possible to prevent stack allocation of an object and only allow it to be instantiated with 'new'?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Is it possible to prevent stack allocation of an object and only allow it to be instiated with 'new' on the heap?

Comment: The reverse, which may also be interesting to readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985/how-to-prevent-an-object-being-created-on-the-heap

Answer (score 88, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to make the constructors private and only allow construction through a static method that returns a pointer. For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ~Foo();
    static Foo* createFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
private:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
};
```

Comment: Or better still a static function that returns a std::unique_ptr<Foo>.

Comment: **Related question:** [How do I prevent a class from being allocated via the 'new' operator? (I'd like to ensure my RAII class is always allocated on the stack.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124856/how-do-i-prevent-a-class-from-being-allocated-via-the-new-operator-id-like)

Comment: But why make it unassignable too?

Comment: Because if it's heap allocated then the object should not be copied, only its pointer should be copied.

Answer (score 26):

In the case of C++11

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    ~Foo();
    static Foo* createFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }

    Foo(const Foo &) = delete; // if needed, put as private
    Foo & operator=(const Foo &) = delete; // if needed, put as private
    Foo(Foo &&) = delete; // if needed, put as private
    Foo & operator=(Foo &&) = delete; // if needed, put as private

  private:
    Foo();
};
```

Comment: As Scott Meyers stated in "Item 11: Prefer deleted functions to private undefined ones." his book "Effective Modern C++", it's better to declare deleted member functions `public`. --QUOTE-- "By convention, deleted functions are declared `public`, not `private`. There’s a reason for that. When client code tries to use a member function, C + + checks accessibility before deleted status. When client code tries to use a deleted `private` function, some compilers complain only about the function being `private`, even though the function’s accessibility doesn’t really affect whether it can be used."

Comment: --QUOTE-- "It’s worth bearing this in mind when revising legacy code to replace `private`-and-not-defined member functions with deleted ones, because making the new functions `public` will generally result in better error messages."

Comment: Must. Give. Moar. Up. Votes.

Answer (score 12):

You could make the constructor `private`, then provide a `public` static factory method to create the objects.

Answer (score 6):

The following allows public constructors and will stop stack allocations by throwing at runtime. Note `thread_local` is a C++11 keyword.

```
class NoStackBase {
    static thread_local bool _heap;
protected:
    NoStackBase() {
        bool _stack = _heap;
        _heap = false;
        if (_stack)
            throw std::logic_error("heap allocations only");
    }
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { 
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new(size);
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw () {
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new(size, nothrow_value);
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size, void* ptr) throw () {
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new(size, ptr);
    }
    void* operator new[](size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new[](size);
    }
    void* operator new[](size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value) throw () {
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new[](size, nothrow_value);
    }
    void* operator new[](size_t size, void* ptr) throw () {
        _heap = true;
        return ::operator new[](size, ptr);
    }
};

bool thread_local NoStackBase::_heap = false;
```

Comment: I don't think you need `_stack` as a data member. Having it as a simple stack variable inside the `NoStackBase` constructor should do.

Comment: You also don't need to make the destructor `virtual`. Nobody can delete a derived class via a `NoStackBase` anyway.

Comment: since you explicitly call global operator new, I assume this won't call any custom operator overload those objects have defined (?), and forcing the use of those may be the motivating reason for this question

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible in C++20 using a destroying operator delete, see [p0722r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0722r3.html).

```
#include <new>

class C
{
private:
  ~C() = default;
public:
  void operator delete(C *c, std::destroying_delete_t)
  {
    c->~C();
    ::operator delete(c);
  }
};
```

Note that the private destructor prevents it from being used for anything else than dynamic storage duration. But the destroying operator delete allows it to be destroyed via a delete expression (as the delete expression does not implicitly call the destructor in this case).

Answer (score -2):

You could create a header file that provides an abstract interface for the object, and factory functions that return pointers to objects created on the heap.

```
// Header file

class IAbstract
{
    virtual void AbstractMethod() = 0;

public:
    virtual ~IAbstract();
};

IAbstract* CreateSubClassA();
IAbstract* CreateSubClassB();

// Source file

class SubClassA : public IAbstract
{
    void AbstractMethod() {}
};

class SubClassB : public IAbstract
{
    void AbstractMethod() {}
};

IAbstract* CreateSubClassA()
{
    return new SubClassA;
}

IAbstract* CreateSubClassB()
{
    return new SubClassB;
}
```