# What does "delete this" mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Delete this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)

What does it mean to `delete this` pointer from a member function?

According to my understanding:
    `new` returns `this` pointer, which we pass to `delete`, which in turn calls the destructor before freeing memory. So `delete this` should do the same thing.

My doubt is whether the destructor will be called or not?

Answer (score 0):

The destructor will be called.

Comment: He asked if the destructor will be called.  I answered.  Why the downvotes?