# Is it undefined behavior to have an object be deleted before its member function returns?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Delete this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)

I am trying to create a system to manage states for a game.

The issue with my current design is that when I switch states, the old state is deleted before control switches over to the new state.

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
class StateManager;

class State
{
public:
    virtual void update(StateManager &manager)= 0;
    virtual ~State(){}
};


class StateManager
{
public:
    void setState(std::unique_ptr<State> && newState )
    {
        currentState = std::move(newState);
    }
    std::unique_ptr<State> currentState;

    void run()
    {
        currentState->update(*this);
    }
};
```

Notice how if a State object calls StateManager::setState while in the update method, there will be a period of time when a member function is being called on an object that has just been destroyed.

A complete example of this behavior is at http://ideone.com/WHLzJL. Note how the destructor for FirstState is called before FirstState::update returns.

Is this undefined behavior in C++?
If so, how should I change my design?

Comment: Perhaps not quite an *exact* duplicate, but the answers to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3150942/179910) cover this as well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I believe 'exact duplicate' should be extended as 'exact duplicate or strict subset'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's okay, if you are careful: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem as long and it is the *last* thing you do in the function.  (`delete this` is a common idiom.)  In this particular case, however, I've generally found it preferable for `State::update` to return the new `State` (which could be `this`).  The code which calls it in `StateManager` will then simply assign it to the pointer.

Be careful of the semantics of smart pointers in this case.  I did it using an invasive shared pointer, but I suspect that most of the current smart pointers will fail here.  On the other hand, you don't really need a smart pointer here, so why add the complication.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the main effect is that `this` becomes a dangling pointer, so accessing fields, calling `virtual` methods or doing something like `dynamic_cast<T*>(this)` that relies on run-time type information would result in undefined behavior.