# Will deleting this call destructor?

Tags: c++, this, destructor, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Delete this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)

There is a class Foobar created on heap. I want to exit application when it dies. It must die, when I call die() function. There are some private properties created on heap - I also need to delete them. I wrote that code:

```
Foobar::Foobar()
{
    m_var = new int(1);
}

Foobar::~Foobar()
{
    delete m_var;
    exit(0);
}

void Foobar::die()
{
    delete this;
}
```

The question is in `delete this` line. If I call it, will `Foobar::~Foobar()` be called, or not?

P.S. If there is better solution, suggest it, please.

Comment: any reason for a `die` function instead of calling `delete` directly?

Comment: The operating system reclaims heap memory when the process exits, though more generally there are types of resources that you do have to explicitly release which would be better rationales for this design.

Comment: @KarthikT yes. I use Qt and it should be called 'cos there are additional code in die() which also must be executed.

Comment: you can put the code that  needs to happen in `die` in `~Foobar`. Maybe safer, especially if you need access to the Foobar object for any of that code

Comment: @honk I created it 'cos it was hard for me to understand answers there. Now it's perfecly clear.

Comment: @KarthikT in Qt there are some things which need it to be called in die() (die is a slot).

Comment: Also if your additional code is after `delete this` they will not be called, since `exit` will be called before that.

Comment: Ah ok, if it is necessary for qt code then we cant avoid it, just be careful that `delete this` is the absolute last piece of code called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the object is allocated dynamically with `new`: Yes, `delete this` will cause the destructor to be called. However, you should be very careful with deleting `this`. In particular, you need to ensure that no subsequent operations try to access any members of the class.

Also, if this is ever done on memory which is not dynamically allocated (i.e. with `new`), this leads to **undefined behaviour**. In fact, this also leads to undefined behaviour if the object was allocated via `new[]`.

See this link for more information:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.15

Here's another SO question about it:
[Is delete this allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)

Comment: >> However, you should be very careful with deleting `this`.
Why? After that I call exit(0) which will exit application and I believe that any code won't be executed (or I am wrong?)

Anyway, die() calls additional code which delete all created objects which can it's members.

Comment: Sure, in this case it looks safe, but as a general rule it is always good to think twice and really make sure that you are safe whenever this pattern is employed.

In this particular case, if you by `delete this` implicitly call `exit`, you really need to think about whether other resources are freed properly, as a call to `exit` means control will never return to where it came from and any resources not handled by RAII may leak.

Comment: Also, see my edit about how the object was allocated (whether it was via `new` or not) (as first pointed out by @Chubsdad)

Comment: I wrote about it in question already - "There is a class Foobar created on heap. I want to exit application when it dies..." Created on the **heap**.

Comment: @IllyaKovalevskyy So I see. Still, it is a very good cautionary reminder (for other users who come by here looking for a quick answer?). So, to conclude: In your special case, there is no danger with this, as long as you're sure no other resources are leaked when calling `exit`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `delete` will call the destructor.

You might also be interested in reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this) SO thread.

---

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you found a nice duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not guaranteed. `delete` should only be called if we are sure that `this` was created using `new`.

So depending on how the current object was created, we may or may not have a destructor called.

So assume that the 'Foobar' object was created on stack (i.e. without `new`). Then `delete this` has an undefined behavior.

OTOH, if it was created using 'new', then `delete this` is safe and will invoke the destructor.

Comment: Good point about the dynamic allocation. Forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: I wrote about it in question already - "There is a class Foobar created on heap. I want to exit application when it dies..." Created on the **heap**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends completely on the way the variable is defined. It is necessary that the variable is defined with the **new** keyword otherwise **delete** does not call the constructor. 
So declare the variable as:
foobar a= new foobar();

Comment: I wrote about it in question already - "There is a class Foobar created on heap. I want to exit application when it dies..."

Created on the **heap**.