# Can i call destructor from its class method?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a Thread class like bellow

```
class Thread {
public:
  Thread();
  ~Thread();
  void start();
  void stop();
}
```

So i need to call destructor from stop() method, is it a good way to do that?

Comment: No, what would happen when the object's lifetime came to an end? It might be better to describe what you need (technically there are corner cases when it might work, but do you want to limit your class to work only in those corner cases?)

Comment: You can `delete this;` it (if it's a stack var), but it's very risky. Why you want that? Can't you `delete` the object after calling `stop` or use some smart pointer? Or just stack variable?

Comment: @KirilKirov: On which stack would a `Thread` be? Not on its own stack, and not on the stack of some other thread, presumably.

Comment: @MSalters A thread is in no way different from any other class on this behalf.

Comment: @MSalters - kind of on both stacks. The user can create object `Thread` (on it's "own" stack) and then `start` will actually create the OS specific thread (which will internally create a thread-specific stack, but it doesn't matter). The thread may operate safely over all private data members and not only, if additionally synchronized. Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed-in-c

Answer (score 8):

Technically yes, but be careful, you should not use the deleted object, `this` and non-static members anymore:

```
delete this;
```

You can also call the destructor:

```
~Thread();
```

However, in a well designed code, you can avoid these types of self destructions.

Comment: +1, You might want to add, not to use `this` or any non-static member variable after the delete statement.

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander: The question implies that the destructor must be explicitly called, i.e. it's not called because the object goes out of scope.

Comment: You cant use delete this, if there is any chance the object might be on the stack. But,sometime there are objects that are never and can never be only the stack. I think this topic is in the C++ FAQ

Comment: Deleting yourself is a very tenuous position to be in (even when valid). Delegate deletion to a management object so that you don't accidentally use any part of yourself after deletion.

Comment: Downvoted because these are completely (and somewhat unrelated) different things: one calls the destructor and then frees a dynamically allocated memory, the other calls the destructor. It doesn't answer the question which is explicitly "calling the destructor from a member function".

Answer (score 5):

Er'body saying don't call `delete this` from within a member function but to notify the owner that the object is ready to be deleted.

I have a service that creates workers but doesn't care about them after they're created.

From within the service class:

```
Worker* w;
[...]
while (1) {
  [...]
  w = new Worker();
  [...]
}
```

Then from within the worker class:

```
void Worker::doWork() {
  [...]
  [...]
  delete this;
}
```

All the service class does is make new workers, so outside of the worker class there are no references to the worker except the pointer `w` which is discarded every time a new worker is created.

In this case i think it makes sense to call `delete this` inside the worker when it has no more work to do (as long as `delete this;` is the last statement in `doWork()` and there are no succesive member calls after `doWork()`.

If you were storing every instance of created worker however, this wouldn't be true anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```
~Thread();
```

But I doubt if you really need this feature of C++. Maybe you should better design your class.

One legal case for explicitly calling destructors is in custom memory managers which you cannot use the `delete` operator to delete the object.

Comment: Correct syntax, solid advice.
You so very rarely wants to initiate a destruction of yourself like that, that people wanting to is almost always a case of wanting the wrong thing.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett outside of placement-new object management, I'm hard pressed to think of a reason anyone *would* want to do this.

Comment: @WhozCraig Agree. In C++ specification §12.4.14: "explicit calls of destructors are rarely needed. One use of such calls is for objects placed at specific addresses using a new-expression with the placement option. Such use of explicit placement and destruction
of objects can be necessary to cope with dedicated hardware resources and for writing memory management facilities."

Comment: @XiangyanSun I feel in good company then, because that (a placement-new situation) is the *only* time i've ever needed to do so, and I've *never* had to manually invoke it *from member function code*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: One other situation which is even more rare than placement new management. Is destroying (explicitly calling destructor) then re-creating the object (explicitly using placement new on the old object location). Seen it done never used it but it is legal to do so (as long as object is not accessed between destruction and re-creation).

Comment: @LokiAstari Ok, i admit I had to do that as an absolutely dreadful hold-my-nose work-around for a piece of code at work once where outstanding pointers sprinkled throughout various contexts of the code could not be changed, but the object had to be "replaced". The stench drove me from the room. thanks for reminding me of that painful day =P

Answer (score 1):

No.

I think that it is bad practice to call destructor from inside the class code.
If you need to do cleanup that is done also in the destructor you should use a cleanup() function to encapsulate that work, and have that function called from stop and from the destructor if relevant.

Obviously such a solution would require keeping the state of the object to know if it was already cleaned up or not, to avoid unneeded work and multiple freeing of resources which might no be yours anymore.

Specifically for your case, I'm not sure why you would want to delete the thread from the stop function, if there is some mechanism managing the threads - it should allocate/deallocate the threads from outside, and not the thread itself which deallocates its own memory when stopping. (The thread should perform cleanup as mentioned above, but no force a call to its own destructor)

Comment: Even if the `cleanup()` is exactly the same as the destructor? e.g. I have some mutex to clean up, the destructor (and `cleanup()`, the same), just try to detect which mutex is owned by current thread and unlock it.  At some point I want to do `cleanup()`, but when the class instance is destroyed, I want the mutex to be unlocked.  So they share exactly the same code.

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't do this.

Have the thread owned by another object.

When you call `stop()` the thread should tell its owner that it is ready to be deleted (make sure you lock yourself so the owner does not delete before you are finished). Then let the owner of the object do the clean up as appropriate (hopefully in the near future).

Comment: Could the downvoter enlighten the rest of us? This seems like perfectly reasonable advice for me, which is likely to lead to better code in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.
that feature is used in COM as each object have a release function which  decrement a private integer of reference count and if it reaches zero it delete the entire object

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to call the destructor from a member function because:

> Destruction sequence
> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after
> executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic
> objects allocated within the body, the compiler calls the destructors
> for all non-static non-variant data members of the class, in reverse
> order of declaration, then it calls the destructors of all direct
> non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in
> turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes,
> etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the
> destructors of all virtual bases.
>
> Even when the destructor is called directly (e.g. obj.~Foo();), the
> return statement in ~Foo() does not return control to the caller
> immediately: it calls all those member and base destructors first.

The pitfall here is that **the destructor doesn't behave as a normal function, but it automatically calls the destructor of all members and base class**.

This obviously could be exploited in special cases but it's not easily known to the average programmer, and probably a comment is needed to explain why it was called explicitly.

Moreover,

> A destructor is a special member function that is called when the
> lifetime of an object ends. The purpose of the destructor is to free
> the resources that the object may have acquired during its lifetime.

**A destructor is automatically called at the end of the lifetime of the object** so if you call it explicitly **you must ensure that the resources you release are not released twice** (for example doubly deleting memory).

**A destructor does not free the memory used by the object**. The memory is freed automatically at the end of the scope, or with `delete` if allocated dynamically. Hence calling `delete this` is not the same as calling the destructor but a completely different thing.

In most cases the simple solution is to have a cleanup function that is called from the member and the destructor:

```cpp
~MyClass() {
    cleanup();
    other_stuff();
}

void stop() {
    some_operations();
    cleanup();
    some_other_operations();
}
```