# Deleting a std::function object within itself

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

Is this well defined behavior?

```
#include <functional>

void foo() {
    auto f = new std::function<void()>;
    *f = [f]() { delete f; };
    (*f)();
    f = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Using the most recent g++, if I do this within a template it causes invalid reads while running under valgrind, otherwise it works fine. Why? Is this a bug in g++?

```
#include <functional>

template<std::size_t>
void foo() {
    auto f = new std::function<void()>;
    *f = [f]() { delete f; };
    (*f)();
    f = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    foo<0>();
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't "well defined". By the way, what do you use it for?

Comment: My implementation of a templated shared pointer. I use the lambda to capture the type for deletion. The deleter also deletes itself after being invoked, since it's no longer needed.

Comment: Do you know which section of the standard mentions that this is undefined behavior? Because it seems to work with clang++ everywhere, and g++ outside of templates.

Comment: in addition, if g++ doesn't compile it, it's much better if you provide your code.

Comment: @clin18 I think that can be answered in the same way you're able to prove that the Tooth Fairy does not exist :)

Comment: @alphashooter You need to use -std=c++11.

Comment: @SanJacinto If there were an ISO standard documenting the existence of mythical creatures, sure.

Comment: @clin18 because you try to delete function wrapper, and is it defined or undefined depends on implementation of std::function

Comment: @clin18 I was joking, but if the standard doesn't mention it, then it's by definition undefined. You're lucky if your undefined behavior is called out.

Comment: @SanJacinto Well the standard gives a definition for lambdas, and std::function, I could simply apply those definitions. I think undefined behaviors are the exception, not the norm, when it comes to language specifications.

Comment: @clin18 `-std=c++11` is it really the answer on my question? or does it determine why the compilation breaks? :)

Comment: @alphashooter I must have misunderstood your question then. It should compile fine. The problem occurs at run time if the code appears in a template.

Comment: @alphashooter can you prove it? Where does the spec say that this has undefined behavior?

Comment: @alphashooter Actually, you'll need valgrind to even see the problem. There are invalid reads all over the place.

Comment: @SanJacinto the standard does not need to say that deleting a `std::function` is defined behavior. It is by default (as deleting a `std::string` is aswell). If this is undefined behavior, IMO it should need an explicit statement that deleting the object during invocation of the bound function object is undefined.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Deleting a `std::function` isn't, but how about doing it within a lambda owned by the `std::function`?

Comment: @clin18 Even now, it isn't clear for me, what is the reason you need to delete the object in this way. There is a vary of methods how you can avoid this, and even if this method works fine in some cases, it may not work in others.

Comment: @alphashooter At this point, the usefulness of this practice is meaningless to me. This question is more driven by curiosity than by practicality.

Comment: @clin18 Well, in this case I can say the following. In your example, deletion of `std::function` during its invokation isn't a good way. The only one situation when you can delete object by itself, directly or not, is when you are sure this object will NEVER be used. No non-static member functions calls, no access to its fields, NOTHING. If you are sure that all this conditions are true, you can use it, in any other case - you should not.

Comment: @alphashooter Sure, I'll null out the `f` right after. This isn't really a "good practice" problem, but a language specification problem.

Comment: Why would this point to a bug in g++? The templated version compiles/runs fine here (I tested it with g++ 4.6). That would be a problem with valgrind then.

Comment: @clin18 But what does `f` stop to do it by itself? :) To the `f`, if it is deleted or not, it doesn't matter. I'm sure, in 99,9% attempts it would work. Maybe, even in 100%. But such things may cause problems.

Comment: Regarding the validity, I would say that there is no way to garantee that the delete statement would be the last statement in the body of the lambda function, so this is probably undefined.

Comment: Well... I tested on my system with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++0x` and it works (that is, it doesn't crash as mentioned in your "question".) I'm on Unbuntu 13.10 with the currently available version of g++ which is 4.8.1. What's yours btw?

Comment: @alphashooter I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. Check out the code again. The deletion occurs within a lambda. Which is managed by `f` but it is not `f`.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I'm using 4.9. The problem is that it generates vastly different code apparently. It runs fine with g++ without templates, clang++ with or without templates, but not g++ with templates.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I have explicitly made the `delete` the only statement.

Comment: @AlexisWilke It doesn't crash. Try running the template version under valgrind, you'll see invalid reads.

Comment: I know you have, made it the only statement, I was answering "is this well defined?". I don't think it is, because there is no way to ensure it would be the last statement. Also, 4.9 is not stable yet, so any "bug" you think you found might be fixed on the official release.

Comment: @clin18 I said, if object is deleted directly or not, it has no sense. If you call the lambda directly, it's ok. But you call the lambda through `f`.

Comment: Any time you end an object's lifetime (at least of a type whose implementation you do not control) before the end of a member function call on that object, you run the risk that the member function will try to indirect through `this` between the destruction and the end of the call. The standard doesn't guarantee that `std::function` doesn't indirect through `this` between the invocation of the stored function object and the end of the call to `operator()`, so while it might work on one implementation, it certainly isn't portable.

Comment: Looking at the code (see my answer), it would appear that the code is accessign something inside the function object after the destructor - which is bad. I'm using gcc 4.8.2 - the older 4.6.3 that I have from the installation of my Linux doesn't compile the code at all.

Comment: It's perfectly legal for the implementation to do that. Stuart Olsen has it right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150965/541686

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Quote: `Undeﬁned behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit deﬁnition of
behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data.` [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). Is that behavior still defined?

Comment: I didn't have time to edit my last comment, but I wanted to say in addition, the Standard doesn't says if there's any guarantee that `std::function` would try to access `this` after invokation, the same is for lambda destructor. So it seems to be exactly undefined behavior.

Comment: @alphashooter are you saying that this is undefined behaior: `int foo = 0;` ? The Standard does not explicitly define behavior for a variable definition of name "foo".

Comment: @alphashooter OK the latter comment makes more sense to me.. but does it allow touching `this` after invocation? I mean, if it does touch `this`, then the program behavior becomes undefined if it deletes `this`. If it is a program that uses the component according to the Standard (and the Standard makes no explicit mention about not deleting `this` of the object, so I don't understand how to derive what is allowed and what not here), then a library implementation cannot simply render the program's behavior undefined. So my question is: what is the order of guarantees?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I will give an example in the context of this question. For `std::function`, the Standard says that this is a generalization of function objects and defines that the invokation must return the result which is the same as the passed functional object would return. Nothing more. You should understand, all this rules work until the cirqumstance is... «ideal». Calling `delete` during the invokation, you meddle in the object work and corrupt it. So you leave yourself a chance to get access violation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This program has well-defined behavior and demonstrates a g++ bug.

The only questionable part of runtime is during the statement `(*f)();`.  The behavior of that line can be picked apart piece by piece.  The Standard section numbers below are from N3485; apologies if some don't match C++11.

`*f` is just the built-in unary operator on a raw pointer to class type.  No problem here.  The only other evaluation is the function-call expression `(*f)()`, which invokes `void std::function<void()>::operator() const`.  Then that full-expression is a discarded value.

20.8.11.2.4:

```
R operator()(ArgTypes... args) const
```

> Effects: *`INVOKE`*`(obj, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` where `obj` is the target object of `*this`.

(I've replaced "`f`" in the Standard with "`obj`" to reduce confusion with `main`'s `f`.)

Here `obj` is a copy of the lambda object, `ArgTypes` is the empty parameter pack from the specialization `std::function<void()>`, and `R` is `void`.

The *`INVOKE`* pseudo-macro is defined in 20.8.2.  Since the type of `obj` is not a pointer-to-member, *`INVOKE`*`(obj, void)` is defined to be `obj()` implicitly converted to `void`.

5.1.2p5:

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* has a public `inline` function call operator ...

... with exactly described declaration.  In this case it turns out to be `void operator() const`.  And its definition is exactly described too:

5.1.2p7:

> The *lambda-expression*'s *compound-statement* yields the *function-body* of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup, determining the type and value of `this` and transforming *id-expressions* referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using `(*this)`, the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.

5.1.2p14:

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.

5.1.2p17:

> Every *id-expression* that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

So the lambda function call operator must be equivalent to:

```
void __lambda_type::operator() const {
    delete __unnamed_member_f;
}
```

(where I've invented some names for the unnamed lambda type and unnamed data member.)

The single statement of that call operator is of course equivalent to `delete (*this).__unnamed_member_f;`  So we have:

- The built-in unary `operator*` dereference (on the prvalue `this`)
- A member access expression
- A value computation (aka lvalue-to-rvalue conversion) for the member subobject
- A scalar `delete` expression

  - Invokes `std::function<void()>::~function()`
  - Invokes `void operator delete(void*)`

And finally, in 5.3.5p4:

> The *cast-expression* in a *delete-expression* shall be evaluated exactly once.

(Here is where g++ is wrong, doing a second value computation on the member subobject between the destructor call and the deallocation function.)

This code cannot cause any other value computations or side effects after the `delete` expression.

There are some allowances for implementation-defined behavior in lambda types and lambda objects, but none that affect anything above:

5.1.2p3:

> An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:
>
> - the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable,
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class, or
> - whether the closure type is a POD class.

Comment: Makes sense, why the difference between template and no template though?

Comment: To answer that you would need to dig through the g++ code.

Comment: `R std::function<R(Args...)>::operator()(Args&&...) const` what have I missed if deletion of `this` through a constant function, even indirectly, is called well-defined?

Comment: This isn't literally calling `delete this`. it's deleting a pointer which happens to be equal to `this`. This is not a guarantee covered by `const`. Similarly, you could have a pointer to an object and a pointer to the same object as const, and call delete on the normal pointer.

Comment: This does not define whether or not the `std::function::operator()` operator can read or write through `this` after the INVOKE expression has returned.

Comment: Well, it's `operator() const` so we know it can't write through `this`.

Comment: @DeadMG I think the standard is explicitly stating here that the `INVOKE` expression must be the only effect of the `operator()` call.

Comment: @DeadMG It doesn't say whether or not `std::function::operator()` can launch the US nuclear arsenal at Lichtenstein after the INVOKE expression has returned, either. It doesn't need to do so, because descriptions of behavior in the standard are taken to be total.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not well-defined behaviour in general.

Between the end of execution of function object, and the end of the call to `operator()`, the member `operator()` is executing on a deleted object. If the implementation reads or writes through `this`, which it is perfectly allowed to do, then you'll get read or write of a deleted object.

More specifically, the object was only just deleted by this very thread, so it's highly unlikely that any thread actually got around to using it between deletion and the read/write or it was unmapped, so it's quite unlikely to actually cause problems in a simple program. In addition, there's little *apparent* reason for the implementation to read or write to `this` after it returns.

However, Valgrind is quite correct that any such read or write would be very invalid and in some circumstances, could lead to random crashes or memory corruption. It's easy to suggest that, between deleting `this` and a hypothetical read/write, this thread was pre-empted and another thread allocated and used that memory. Alternatively, the memory allocator decided it had enough cached memory of this size and returned this segment to the OS immediately upon freeing it. This is an excellent candidate for a Heisenbug since the conditions to cause it would be relatively rare and only apparent in real complex executing systems rather than trivial test programs.

You could get away with it *if* you can prove that there are no reads or writes after the function object finishes returning. This basically means guaranteeing the implementation of `std::function<Sig>::operator()`.

Edit:

Mats Peterson's answer raises an interesting question. GCC appears to have implemented the lambda by doing something like this:

```
struct lambda { std::function<void()>* f; };
void lambda_operator(lambda* l) {
    l->f->~std::function<void()>();
    ::operator delete(l->f);
}
```

As you can see, the call to `operator delete` makes a load from `l` after it's just been deleted, which is exactly the scenario I described above. I'm not actually sure what C++11's memory model rules say about this, I would have thought it was illegal but not necessarily. It might not be defined either way. If it is not illegal, you are definitely screwed.

Clang, however, seems to generate this operator:

```
void lambda_operator(lambda* l) {
    auto f = l->f;
    f->~std::function<void()>();
    ::operator delete(f);
}
```

Here when `l` is deleted it doesn't matter because `f` was copied into local storage.

To a certain extent, this definitively answers your question- GCC *absolutely does* load from the memory of the lambda after it's been deleted. Whether or not that's Standard-legal or not, I'm not sure. You could definitely work around this by employing a user-defined function. You'd still have the problem of the std::function implementation issuing loads or stores to `this`, though.

Comment: "If the implementation reads or writes through this, which it is perfectly allowed to do". Why is it allowed to do so? After all, if it does, then the program's behavior becomes undefined!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Because it is the implementation of the standard library. It is well-formed, so it supposed to have predictable behavior. And if _you use_ it, you _must_ provide its behavior will defined in your program. _You_ use it. If it is bad for you that object allowed to read/write through `this` during member function invokation, it's your problem, not of the standard library, such as any other if it's well-formed.

Comment: @Johannes: There is no wording in the Standard banning the implementation from issuing reads and writes through `this` after the function object's `operator()` has returned. And it is the implementation so they can implement `operator()` however they like. No function can be assumed to be legal to be operating on a deleted object unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: @DeadMG *"There is no wording in the Standard banning the implementation from issuing reads and writes through this after the function object's operator() has returned."* - yes because we have "If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute that program."

Comment: However, on std-discussion, Ville pointed to http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2224, which points out that we have a non-normative rule that forbids programs to delete a standard library object during the invocation of its member functions and which is going to be "normativated". Your answer would be better if you considered that this is a Standards defect but that the intent is that deleting the object is forbidden.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't believe that the resolution of 2224 would apply to this case. The normative statement "If an object of a standard library type **is accessed** [emphasis mine], and the beginning of the object's lifetime (3.8 [basic.life]) does not happen before the access, or the access does not happen before the end of the object's lifetime, the behavior is undefined unless otherwise specified." since - as explained in aschepler's answer - there is no access to the `std::function` after the invocation occurs in `operator()`. The actual access is within the lifetime proper.

Comment: @Casey on the std-discussion list, me and others have pointed this out aswell (which roots on the sloppy use of "access"). This is still an open issue report, so the solution proposed there does not necessarily reflect the committee's opinion by high probability (as is true with issue resolutions that are put into the spec). It's different with notes that *are* in the spec, which *do* express the committee's intent with high probability, just not *normatively*. And in our case, the note in the spec renders the code in this question undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to lambdas or std::function, but rather the semantics of delete. This code exhibits the same problem:

```
class A;

class B {
    public:
        B(A *a_) : a(a_) {}
        void foo();
    private:
        A *const a;
};

class A {
    public:
        A() : b(new B(this)) {}
        ~A() {
            delete b;
        }
        void foo() { b->foo(); }
    private:
        B *const b;
};

void B::foo() {
    delete a;
}

int main() {
    A *ap = new A;
    ap->foo();
}
```

The issue is the semantics of delete. Is it allowed to load the operand again from memory after calling its destructor, in order to free its memory?

Comment: Good find.  In this case, it all comes down to 5.3.5p4 "The _cast-expression_ in a _delete-expression_ shall be evaluated exactly once."  I read "evaluated" as including all the sorts of actions 3.8 forbids on a pointer to/glvalue referencing a destroyed object.

Comment: @aschepler: I think your reading is right. This was actually in some code that clin18 submitted for a class that I teach. We were trying to track down if it was his code that was not compliant or g++ that was not compliant. (We knew that clang++ was fine with it.)

Answer (score 2):

See http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2224.

Accessing a library type after its destructor has started is undefined behavior. Lambdas are not library types, so they don't have such a limitation. Once a destructor of a library type has been entered, the invariants of that library type no longer hold. The language doesn't enforce such a limitation because invariants are by and large a library concept, not a language concept.

Comment: Note this is correspondence for a document discussing potential problems in the standard, "strictly unofficial and subject to change at the whim of the LWG chair." It was already posted and discussed in more detail by Johannes Schaub, above. It also still doesn't resolve the issue of whether OP is actually accessing the object at deletion.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably not crash in the a general case, but WHY on earth would you ever want to do something like that in the first place.

But here's my analysis:

valgrind produces:

```
==7323==    at 0x4008B5: _ZZ3fooILm0EEvvENKUlvE_clEv (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==7323==    by 0x400B4A: _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZ3fooILm0EEvvEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==7323==    by 0x4009DB: std::function<void ()()>::operator()() const (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==7323==    by 0x40090A: void foo<0ul>() (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
==7323==    by 0x4007E8: main (in /home/MatsP/src/junk/a.out)
```

This points at the code here (which is indeed the lambda function in your original code):

```
000000000040088a <_ZZ3fooILm0EEvvENKUlvE_clEv>:
  40088a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40088b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40088e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400892:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  400896:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  40089a:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  40089d:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax   ;; Null check - don't delete if null. 
  4008a0:   74 1e                   je     4008c0 <_ZZ3fooILm0EEvvENKUlvE_clEv+0x36>
  4008a2:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4008a6:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  4008a9:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
;; Call function destructor
  4008ac:   e8 bf ff ff ff          callq  400870 <_ZNSt8functionIFvvEED1Ev>  
  4008b1:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4008b5:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax           ;; invalid access
  4008b8:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
;; Call delete. 
  4008bb:   e8 b0 fd ff ff          callq  400670 <_ZdlPv@plt>   ;; delete
  4008c0:   c9                      leaveq 
  4008c1:   c3                      retq
```

Interestingly, it "works" using clang++ (version 3.5, built from git sha1 d73449481daee33615d907608a3a08548ce2ba65, from March 31st):

```
0000000000401050 <_ZZ3fooILm0EEvvENKUlvE_clEv>:
  401050:   55                      push   %rbp
  401051:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401054:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  401058:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  40105c:   48 8b 7d f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
  401060:   48 8b 3f                mov    (%rdi),%rdi
  401063:   48 81 ff 00 00 00 00    cmp    $0x0,%rdi   ;; Null check. 
  40106a:   48 89 7d f0             mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)
  40106e:   0f 84 12 00 00 00       je     401086 <_ZZ3fooILm0EEvvENKUlvE_clEv+0x36> 
  401074:   48 8b 7d f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdi
  401078:   e8 d3 fa ff ff          callq  400b50 <_ZNSt8functionIFvvEED2Ev>   
;; Function destructor 
  40107d:   48 8b 7d f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rdi
  401081:   e8 7a f6 ff ff          callq  400700 <_ZdlPv@plt>    ;; delete. 
  401086:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  40108a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40108b:   c3                      retq
```

Edit: It doesn't really make any sense - I don't see why there is a memory access to the first element inside the function class in gcc's code and not in clang's - they are supposed to do the same thing...

Comment: Interesting- the compiler loaded `f` twice. I'm not sure that is legal under the C++11 memory model.

Comment: Looking at the (rather messy - I'm sure for good reason) functional header file, there seem to be some _M_access involved (but maybe only if the function has actual arguments?).

Answer (score 1):

The allocation `auto f = new std::function<void()>;` of course is alright. The definition of the lambda `*f = [f]() { delete f; };` works as well, as it is not executed yet.

Now the interesting thing is `(*f)();`. First it dereferences `f`, then calls `operator()` and finally executes `delete f`. Calling `delete f` in the class member function `function<>::operator()` is the same as calling `delete this`. [Under certain cirqumstances](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html) this is legal.

So it depends on how `operator()` for `std::function` and lamdabs is implemented. Your code would be valid if it is guaranteed that no member function, member variable or the this pointer itself are used or even touched by `operator()` after executing your encapsulated lambda.

I would say there is no need for `std::function` to call other member functions or use member variables in `operator()` after executing your lambda. So you will probably find implementations for which your code is legal, but in general it is probably not safe to assume so.