# Return value after delete this;

Tags: c++, return-value, member-functions, delete-operator

Let's say I've got a class A

```
class A {
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
    bool foo(int);
};

bool A::foo(int i){

    if(i==10){
        delete this;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){

    A *pnt = new A();
    if(pnt->foo(10)){
        cout<<"deleted with foo"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        delete pnt;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Is this ok or is it undefined behavior that foo will return true?

I'm asking what happens to the member function after "`delete this;`".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this

Comment: Reopened: the "duplicate" is about `delete this;` in `void` functions. This question is not whether `delete this;` is OK; it is whether `return true;` is OK after doing `delete this;` .

Comment: The C++ FAQ entry suggests it is OK but it'd be good to see Standard references

Comment: Your member function is not referencing anything belonging to `*this` after deleting `this`, nor does the code in `main`, so it is OK. But it may of course lead to surprises if a different programmer maybe doesn't expect that the object is gone because he never deleted it (be positively sure to name the deleting member function in a way so this is communicated!). Note that you may not access _anything_ belonging to the class instance (not just data fields), including non-static member functions.

Comment: The standard says it's OK to `delete this`, period. It does not say it OK to `delete this` only in functions that return `void`. That would be a rather strange and unmotivated restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched in [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) for current standard and also read the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this) referenced in comments and the FAQ.

I could not find any elements saying that this code should lead to Undefined Behaviour.

The standard says :

- *the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer
  value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression* : fine `this` is correct in above code
- *If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, the delete-expression will
  invoke the destructor (if any) for the object* : fine, destructor does nothing ...
- *If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, then:
  If the allocation call for the new-expression for the object to be deleted was not omitted and the
  allocation was not extended (5.3.4), the delete-expression shall call a deallocation function* : fine, object will be deallocated

As the code in not in the allocated part of object and as after `delete this`, code only uses the constant value `true`, there is no reason for the code to lead to UB. FAQ (and answers to ref<sup>ed</sup> question) clearly indicates that `delete this` is valid and idiomatic C++.

So there is no reason why `return true` should not be executed.

That being said, as for any other usage of `delete this` programmer must ensure to use it only on objects allocated with new because if not it is indeed UB.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it 'delete this' makes the object pointed to by the this pointer invalid.

As such it IS undefined to use any member variables; and you can't call virtual (polymorphic) functions (because you don't have a vtable anymore). However you can do anything else that you need to including (as in your case) returning a value.