# Destroying object in member function C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, self-destruction

```
class Base{
  virtual void sth() =0;
  virtual void destroy_me(){}
};

class Derived : public Base{
  void sth(){}
  void destroy_me(){
    delete this;
  }
};
```

Is this safe behavior if I am absolutely sure that `Derived` was dynamically allocated? I don't want to use a destructor as some derived classes in my design are not supposed to destroy themselves while others are, e.g.

```
class Safe : public Base{
  void sth(){};
  void destroy_me(){return;}
}
```

Classes of type `Safe` are supposed to be deallocated the 'proper' way by calling `delete`.

EDIT:
To give more info why I am doing this. I have a binary tree structure of the type

```
class Node{
  private:
    Node* lhs;
    Node* rhs;
  public:
    Base* compute();   // recursive
};
```

The idea is that I am using `Derived` for some temporary computations while `Safe` is an object stored in a proper data structure. If `compute()` returns a pointer to `Derived` I would like to delete it while if it returns a pointer to `Safe`, I want to keep the object as it will always be stored in another data structure that I properly deallocate at the end of the program.

Comment: Only if you're 100% sure that you are not, in fact, in a derived class of `Derived`.

Comment: For context, could you elaborate on the thinking behind *"some derived classes in my design are not supposed to destroy themselves while others are"*?

Comment: You must actually have a destructor because `delete this;` will invoke it. But the destructor can be protected or private. Also, if you intend to call this on classes derived from Derived, then Derived must have a virtual destructor. (Probably `Base` should too).

Comment: NPE, check the edited question

Comment: With your edit, if you have a pointer to `Base` and you call `object->destroy_me()`, how will you know if you need to also call `delete`?

Comment: So if you have a `Base*` then you don't know whether you're supposed to destroy it with `delete` or with `destroy_me`? Sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: I added one more edit to clarify on my design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Delete this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/c-delete-this)