# std::function delete-itself when during its call?

Tags: c++11

In some case, I have to std::function delete-itself during std::function call :

```
    std::function<void (void)> test;
    std::shared_ptr<int> tt = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    test = [=,&test]() 
    {
        std::cout << tt.use_count() << std::endl;
        test = nullptr; // destroy self
        return;
    };
    std::cout << tt.use_count() << std::endl;
    tt = nullptr;
    test();
```

is it will be a problem ? Because it destroy it-self during its call.It's OK for vs2015 and xcode. 
Or I should write like this :

```
test = [=,&test]() 
    {
        std::shared_ptr<void> raii(nullptr,[&](){ test = nullptr;  }); // destroy itself
        std::cout << tt.use_count() << std::endl;
        return;
    };
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by clearing the `std::function` object? It should not release a significant amount of memory. The actual machine code of the function can't be deleted (easily).

Comment: I just write some test code. In my project, I came across one case like this. I just wanna know, if i call std::function and destroy itself during its call. Will it be a problem ?

Comment: It seems that this situation is largely equivalent to [calling `delete this` from a member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed): For stateful lambdas and function objects, the `std::function` has ownership which is released by the `nullptr` assignment. This happens within a member function call to `operator()()` on the function object.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda function is basically a closure object implementing its callable operator. This object is copied into the `std::function` which use the HEAP for it.

You might test this with the following simple example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
void myTest( std::function<int()> &ref)
{
    static int vs = 4;
    int v = vs;
    ref = [v]()->int{return v;};
    vs++;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int()> test;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        myTest(test);
        std::cout << "Another closure call: " << test() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "sizeof function: " << sizeof(test) << std::endl;
}
```

Considering that, and the following question, you could reset the function, of course, taking care of not accessing further members.

> [Is delete this allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed#3150965)

**is it will be a problem ?** Not if you do not access members.

**Or I should write like this?** It is more secure for yourself, but not required.

Comment: But you can assign a nullptr to a `std::function` object: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operator=/

Comment: Sorry, did not understood correctly the question. Hope is better now.

Comment: 3ku very much :)