# Can I delete a std::function object from within its target function during invocation?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, lifetime, std-function

Can I delete a `std::function` object from within the function being called by its `operator()`? Like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::function<void()>* fn = nullptr;
    fn = new std::function<void()>([&fn](){
        std::cout << "In my lambda\n";
        delete fn;       // Is this undefined behaviour?
        // fn = nullptr; // This definitely *is* undefined behviour!
    });
    (*fn)(); // Call lambda
    return 0;
}
```

This is a very stripped down version of the true situation. The real code smart pointers rather than explicit `new` and `delete` (of course), and really the function is removing itself from an STL data structure.

I am interested in two questions:

- Is this definitely not undefined behaviour according to the C++ standard?
- Do implementations allow this in practice? Even if this is allowed in theory, if it's such an unusual edge case that implementations may crash in practice then I still want to avoid it!

Similar questions that have been asked before:

- This is similar to the many questions about `delete this` (e.g. [Is delete this allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed)). This question is different though because it depends on the *library* part of the standard as well as the language: if `std::function` is allowed to access any member variables after it calls its contained function then this is undefined behaviour.
- There are one or two questions that are more similar to this one (e.g. [std::function delete-itself when during its call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884958/stdfunction-delete-itself-when-during-its-call)) but they seem to be interested in, roughly speaking, whether it's probably going to be alright in their application rather than whether the C++ standard specifically allows it. Certainly none of the answers I've seen have mentioned the C++ standard for `std::function`.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense to me. Why would you ever use a pointer to a `std::function`? What is the use-case? What is the *Actual* problem you want to solve using pointers to `std::function`? And no, you can't `delete fn` in the function, because the lambda is a temporary object of an unnamed class that the compiler generates, and the variable `fn` is a member of that class (implementation detail though, but basically the only sane way to implement captures), and by deleting `fn` you kind of pull your own rug out from under yourself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [citation needed]

Comment: I don't really see any difference from `delete this`. `std::function`  is just another class that doesn't use any intrinsics. You could implement it yourself just as well.

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev The fact that `delete this` is allowed doesn't stop there being a problem with `std::function`, because perhaps during `operator()` it could access one of its data memebers after calling the user function (which in my case would `delete this`), which would definitely cause undefined behaviour. Unless the standard explicitly says that implementations cannot do this, then it could potentially occur.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using a [`grpc::CompletionQueue`](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_completion_queue.html), whose API is outside of my control. When an event completes, all you get back to identify the event is a `void*`, and `std::function` has larger footprint than a regular pointer so this `void*` must be a pointer to the function, which I must allocate on the heap (potentially as part of a larger struct). The context is a larger application with more details than I can fit into a comment.