# Why isn't the new operator declared as [[nodiscard]]?

Tags: c++, c++17, nodiscard

C++17 introduced the new attribute `[[nodiscard]]` in [p0189r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0189r1.pdf). When a function is decorated with this attribute, the return type must not be discarded. If it is discarded, a warning is emitted.

Example:

```
[[nodiscard]] void* allocateMemory();

void doWork() {
    allocateMemory(); // Warning is emitted, because the value is not stored in a variable and thus is discarded
}
```

This seems to be a good addition for any function that returns anything that later must be freed/destroyed/deleted/... again. However, the standard did not change the definition of the global new operator to make use of this new annotation. Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: Backwards compatibility pole vaults to mind.

Comment: @stark It would be backwards compatible though. It just emits a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: Lots of us compile with `-Werror`, meaning warnings are errors too.

Comment: @JohnZwinck In that case this special warning could be discarded with another compile flag (forgot which one but I think there is one). Even with backwards compatability in mind, isn't code which does not safe the return value of new just plain wrong? Maybe the question could be converted to "When does it make sense to discard the return value of new?".

Comment: https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=271. It simply came in too late for C++17.

Comment: @T.C. you can create a self-deleting object with operator new...

Comment: @Massa How? Afaik you can't. RAII does not count because RAII also calls delete.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher you can `new` a suicidal object (that even puts itself in some container somewhere); see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed

Comment: @T.C. You should probably expand that into a full answer.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher Qt does this all the time, with parent/child objects.

Answer (score 0):

The paper [P0600R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0600r0.pdf) proposes applying `[[nodiscard]]` to Library functions and it enumerates the global `operator new` as one of the functions it must be applied to.
As mentioned by TC in the comments, this could not make it to the C++17 standard itself. A bug titled: ["`[[nodiscard]]` in the Library"](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=271) was also filed. It was decided to adopt this into a later draft.

The standard draft **n4713** incorporates this change.

> 6.6.4.4 Dynamic storage duration [basic.stc.dynamic]
>   ...
>   2. ... The following allocation and deallocation functions are implicitly declared in global scope in each translation unit of a program.
>
> ```
> [[nodiscard]] void* operator new(std::size_t);
> [[nodiscard]] void* operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t);
> ```