# Continue execution after being deleted in constructor

Tags: c++

I was checking some code and I encountered the following scenario. It's working fine but it sounds like an undefined behaviour to me but I don't know what to search and how to prove it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Child
{
public:
    Child()
    {
        std::cout << "Child created\n";
    }
    ~Child()
    {
        std::cout << "Child is dead\n";
    }
};

class Parent
{
    std::unique_ptr<Child> m_child;
public:
    using Callback = std::function<void()>;
    Parent(const Callback& killMe)
    {
        std::cout << "Parent created\n";
        killMe();
        m_child = std::make_unique<Child>();
    }

    ~Parent()
    {
        std::cout << "Parent is dead\n";
    }
};

class GrandParent
{
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> m_child;
public:
    GrandParent()
    {
        m_child = std::make_unique<Parent>([this]() { KillChild(); });
    }

    void KillChild()
    {
        m_child.reset();
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        GrandParent gp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that, `Parent` get killed before creation of `Child` but apparently it's not the case, I tried it on multiple compilers and always got the following output :

```
Parent created
Child created
Parent is dead
Child is dead
```

Comment: What's that killMe() function ?

Comment: _"...For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after the body of the destructor is executed, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class,..."_ see __Destruction sequence__ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor  So after `Parent::~Parent()` has been executed the members of `Parent` are destroyed.  If `killMe()` does anything then leaving it's definition out of the question is a mistake.

Comment: @PierrePodevin The callback function which passed to `Parent` by `GrandParent`.

Comment: re question title: where is the delete in the constructor?  Have you left some code out of the question?

Comment: @RichardCritten `Parent` class constructor.

Comment: No `delete` there - please post a [mcve] so we don't have to guess what unseen code does and how it does it.

Comment: @RichardCritten `Grandparent` has a pointer to `Parent`. When constructing `Parent`, it passes a callback to `Grandparent::KillChild`, which will call `delete`(in `reset()`) on `Parent` object that is currently being constructed. This already is minimal and reproducible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed  So __UB__ as the code accesses a member after the delete.

Comment: `delete this` question has good reasoning why there is UB (accessing members after delete), but I wonder if calling destructor from within the constructor is actually defined behaviour.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It only "works" because `m_child.reset()` is called when `m_child` isn't assigned yet, so becomes a no-op. Otherwise `killMe()` would delete the instance and the subsequent `m_child = ...` would access a deleted object.

Comment: @rustyx I'm sorry misread your comment the first time but now I think you are completely right. I didn't look at it that way! I would accept it if you post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code has no UB only because it doesn't work as intended.

```
    m_child = std::make_unique<Parent>([this]() { KillChild(); })
```

Here

1. A instance of `Parent` is constructed

   - which calls `killMe()` which calls `KillChild()`
   - `KillChild()` calls `m_child.reset()`, which does nothing because `m_child` is empty
2. *then* `m_child` is assigned

If it did work as intended, you'd get a use-after-free after `killMe()`:

```
killMe();
m_child = std::make_unique<Child>(); // is actually this->m_child = , but *this* is gone now
```