# Is it possible to overload delete operator to set the pointer to null?

Tags: c++

What I want to do is overload the delete operator for my class to automatically set the pointer to null after deleting it so I can safe delete it inside a member function, like that:

```
# include <iostream>

class Buddy
{
    public:

    Buddy(void) : _hp(100) { }
    ~Buddy(void) { std::cout << "Buddy is dead!" << std::endl; }

    void operator delete(void * ptr)
    {
        ::delete (Buddy*)ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
    }

    void getDamage(int amount)
    {
        _hp -= amount;
        if (_hp <= 0)
            delete this;
    }


    private:

    int _hp;
};

void hitBuddy(Buddy *buddy)
{
    if (!buddy)
        std::cout << "Buddy is already dead!" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Hitting buddy!" << std::endl;
        buddy->getDamage(70);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Buddy *dude = new Buddy;

    hitBuddy(dude);
    hitBuddy(dude);
    hitBuddy(dude);
    return (0);
}
```

But it doesn't set the pointer to null and it calls two times the destructor, is there a proper way to set the pointer to null inside the class like I want to do?
(OUTPUT)

```
Hitting buddy!
Hitting buddy!
Buddy is dead!
Buddy is dead!
Hitting buddy!
Buddy is dead!
Buddy is dead!
a.out(79480,0x10d3cbdc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe345c05790: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(79480,0x10d3cbdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    79480 abort      ./a.out
```

Comment: You'd need a `void operator delete(void*&);` for that. Nope ...

Comment: I suspect that there's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) hidden here. Have you perhaps started to paint yourself into a corner and try to get out by rebuilding the skyscraper bottom-up? There's nothing wrong with redesigning as Eugene implies. It's just part of the process.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed I think the code also has undefined behaviour after the 1st call to `delets this;`

Comment: You also leak a `dude`...

Comment: @RichardCritten `delete this` is well defined.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is but subsequent access to the deleted object is not.

Comment: @RichardCritten That does indeed sound undefined :-)

Comment: No.The standard permits an `operator delete()` that accepts a `void *` argument (passed by value), not one that accepts a `void *&` (which, if permitted, would allow what ou want).  The real solution is to use standard smart pointers (or containers if you need to manage collection of objects rather than one) and - wherever possible - avoid explicit use of any form of operators `new` or `delete` directly.   Doing that tends avoids a need to set pointers to null after deleting them, because the smart pointer destroys the object it manages when it, itself, ceases to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With smart ptr abuse, you might do:

```
class Buddy
{
    Buddy() = default;
    Buddy(const Buddy&) = delete;
    Buddy& operator=(const Buddy&) = delete;
public:

    ~Buddy() { std::cout << "Buddy is dead!" << std::endl; }

    void getDamage(int amount)
    {
        _hp -= amount;
        if (_hp <= 0)
            self.reset();
    }

    static std::weak_ptr<Buddy> make() { auto p = new Buddy; return p->self; }

private:
    int _hp = 100;
    std::shared_ptr<Buddy> self{this};
};

void hitBuddy(std::weak_ptr<Buddy> buddy_weak)
{
    auto buddy = buddy_weak.lock();

    if (!buddy) {
        std::cout << "Buddy is already dead!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Hitting buddy!" << std::endl;
        buddy->getDamage(70);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::weak_ptr<Buddy> dude = Buddy::make();

    hitBuddy(dude);
    hitBuddy(dude);
    hitBuddy(dude);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16aed7f9e8b185e7)

Answer (score 4):

No. It is not possible to overload `operator delete` so that it sets the pointer to null.

This is because the standard requires the first parameter to `operator delete` (which is the pointer to be deleted) to have type `void*` and thus the `operator delete` only receives a copy of the pointer and cannot modify the original argument. It cannot have type `void*&`. (In C++20, "destroying delete" is supported, in which case the parameter shall have type `C*` but still no references are allowed.)

The *implementation* is allowed to zero out pointers after a *delete-expression* as a technique to help the programmer catch use-after-free bugs but there is no way to do this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a proper way to set the pointer to null inside the class
> like I want to do?

No, it is neither possible nor helpful.

This

```
void operator delete(void * ptr)
    {
        ::delete (Buddy*)ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
```

does not work because the function receives `ptr` by value, so `ptr = nullptr;` only modifies the local copy.

Even if it was possible, it would not help if `Buddy` is not created by `new`. And would be a terrible design in any case.

Comment: In my program I was assuming that Buddy is created only with new, so the best way to add a "death state" to Buddy is to check it's life in main and delete it like this? `if (dude->getLife() <= 0) { delete dude; dude = nullptr; } ` or using smart ptrs?