# Boost.asio OpenSSL HTTPS Proxy Request handshake failed C++

Tags: boost, https, proxy, openssl, asio

I am learning TCP Socket Windows programing with Boost/OpenSSL/VS2019. I guess the below code is a typical server example that echoes received data to the client, it worked as expected when tested with client program. But when tested with a browser such as Chrome or IE11(set proxy IP and port 443 in the browsers), the handshake part always failed with message (handshake failed) "https proxy request (SSL routines, ssl3_get_record) [asio.ssl:336130203]". I generated Self-signed Certificate using OpenSSL for testing, and used it in the client program in the way like ssl_context.load_verify_file("cert.pem"), the test turned out to be good. Then I installed "cert.pem" in IE(and Chrome), set the proxy IP and port 443, I was expecting that the handshake will pass, but unfortunately it always failed with the above message.

My Questions are,

1. In order to make browsers work(the handshake part for now), the domain name or IP, or any other identification info in the Self-signed Certificate has to be accurate to the "proxy" server where I am testing on? I generated a dummy certificate for testing, it has nothing to do with the machine I am testing on. The client program(sends message to the server and receives the message sent back from the server) worked OK with it.
2. I am trying to implement a simple HTTPS relay, I understand there are many things need to do, my HTTP proxy works so far. To incorporate SSL, the first thing I want to ensure the proxy server can accept browsers' connections thru HTTPS/Proxy request, then transport data back and forth. Is there anything specific in the browser for HTTPS proxy request that failed the handshake? Or am I in the wrong way to build HTTPS/SSL relay? Thank you very much.

```
class session
{
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
        boost::asio::ssl::context& context)
        : socket_(io_service, context)
    {
    }

    ssl_socket::lowest_layer_type& socket()
    {
        return socket_.lowest_layer();
    }

    void start()
    {
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_handshake, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "handshake good" << std::endl;

            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "handshake failed " + error.what() << std::endl;

            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

private:
    ssl_socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
 
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
        acceptor_(io_service,
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
        context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
    {
        context_.set_options(
            boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&server::get_password, this));
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("cert.pem");
        context_.use_private_key_file("key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        start_accept();
    }

    std::string get_password() const
    {
        return "test";
    }

    void start_accept()
    {
        session* new_session = new session(io_service_, context_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(session* new_session,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "accept good" << std::endl;

            new_session->start();
        }
        else
        {
            delete new_session;
        }

        start_accept();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};
```

Tried:

1. Generated self-signed Certificate files(cert.pem, key.pem, dh2048.pem) using OpenSSL
2. Build Server and client Program with the above certificates, Server listening on port 443, Client and server is on the same machine. Handshake between client and server went thru, message sent between client and server went thru. Moved the client to a separate PC, it works as well.
3. Installed the above certificate in IE and Chrome on the same machine.
4. Connect browsers with the server via HTTPS proxy on port 443, Handshake failed.

Expected:
Handshake between Browsers and "the Proxy" server goes thru without an error.

Actually Resulted:
browser Handshake failed with message "https proxy request (SSL routines, ssl3_get_record) [asio.ssl:336130203]"

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not an HTTP server. You don't disclose what kind of proxy you're using but, if you just point e.g. Chrome at your server, it doesn't like being treated that way either.

Here's with [the code made self-contained](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8193b4b53777a695):

[image]

I'd suggest starting out with at least a valid HTTP response, e.g.:

```
void handle_read(error_code error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
        res_ = {http::status::ok, 10,
                std::string(data_.data(), bytes_transferred)};

        http::async_write(socket_, res_,
                          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                                      asio::placeholders::error));
    } else {
        delete this;
    }
}
```

This would echo minimal valid HTTP responses ignoring the request:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

foo
bar
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

bar
qux
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

qux
```

We're ignoring the client's request, and we're not warning about content-length or keepalive. Le'ts improve that by going HTTP/1.1:

```
void handle_read(error_code error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!error) {
        res_ = {http::status::ok, 11,
                std::string(data_.data(), bytes_transferred)};
        res_.keep_alive(false);
        res_.prepare_payload();

        http::async_write(socket_, res_,
                          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                                      asio::placeholders::error));
    } else {
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Now we get responses like on `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8989 -quiet -verify_quiet <<< "Hello world"`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 12

Hello world
```

### Does the browser like it better?

Curl doesn't complain:

```
curl -k https://localhost:8989/my/page
GET /my/page HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8989
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
Accept: */*
```

My browser browser sends a load of cookies to the `localhost` domain:

[image]

Not shown in the browser are the actual response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1003
```

In fact, if the request is larger than 1024 bytes, the full request can't even be received before the server blurts out a partial "echo" and disconnects. Let's improve the situation by at least reading the entire request headers:

```
asio::async_read_until(
    socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(data_), "\r\n\r\n",
    boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                asio::placeholders::error,
                asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

See it [In Full On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45efcdd5c77bf87a)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace asio  = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = asio::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;

using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ssl_socket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class session {
  public:
    session(asio::io_service& io_service, ssl::context& context)
        : socket_(io_service, context) {}

    ssl_socket::lowest_layer_type& socket() {
        return socket_.lowest_layer();
    }

    void start() {
        socket_.async_handshake( //
            ssl_socket::server,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_handshake, this,
                        asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_handshake(error_code error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "handshake good" << std::endl;

            asio::async_read_until(
                socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(data_), "\r\n\r\n",
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                            asio::placeholders::error,
                            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        } else {
            std::cout << "handshake failed " + error.what() << std::endl;
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_read(error_code error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error) {
            res_ = {http::status::ok, 11,
                    std::string(data_.data(), bytes_transferred)};
            res_.keep_alive(false);
            res_.prepare_payload();

            http::async_write(socket_, res_,
                              boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                                          asio::placeholders::error));
        } else {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(error_code error) {
        if (!error) {
            socket_.async_read_some( //
                asio::buffer(data_),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                            asio::placeholders::error,
                            asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        } else {
            delete this;
        }
    }

  private:
    ssl_socket                        socket_;
    std::string                       data_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;
};

class server {
  public:
    using Ctx = ssl::context;
    server(asio::io_service& io_service, uint16_t port)
        : io_service_(io_service)
        , acceptor_(io_service, {tcp::v4(), port})
        , context_(Ctx::sslv23) //
    {
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        context_.set_options(Ctx::default_workarounds | Ctx::no_sslv2 |
                             Ctx::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(&server::get_password);
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("cert.pem");
        context_.use_private_key_file("key.pem", Ctx::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        start_accept();
    }

  private:
    static std::string get_password(size_t, Ctx::password_purpose) {
        return "test";
    }

    void start_accept() {
        session* new_session = new session(io_service_, context_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                               boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
                                           new_session,
                                           asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(session* new_session, error_code error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "accept good" << std::endl;
            new_session->start();
        } else {
            delete new_session;
        }

        start_accept();
    }

  private:
    asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor     acceptor_;
    ssl::context      context_;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_service ioc;
    server s(ioc, 8989);

    ioc.run_for(30s);
}
```

### Further Work

In fact, you probably need to read the HTTP request anyways (since the context is browsers and HTTP proxies). So, perhaps use Beast again:

```
void do_receive() {
    http::async_read(
        socket_, buf_, req_,
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    asio::placeholders::error,
                    asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Now we can get rid of the `keep_alive(false)` since we don't clobber our input.

Now, the [`delete this` anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed-in-c/3150965#3150965) can be replaced by the `enable_shared_from_this` pattern.

If we now move the socket creation to the server and avoid passing `io_service&` references, we can also remove the violation of encapsulation that was `socket()` and stop depending on `io_service` which has been deprecated for several Asio versions.

The result is eerily close to the Beast HTTP server examples:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abb984c2dc37bc93)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp> // for the request echo
namespace asio  = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = asio::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;

using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ssl_socket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(tcp::socket s, ssl::context& context)
        : socket_(std::move(s), context) {}

    void start() {
        socket_.async_handshake( //
            ssl_socket::server,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_handshake, shared_from_this(),
                        asio::placeholders::error));
    }

  private:
    void handle_handshake(error_code error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "handshake good" << std::endl;
            do_receive();
        } else {
            std::cout << "handshake failed " + error.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void do_receive() {
        http::async_read(
            socket_, buf_, req_,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                        asio::placeholders::error,
                        asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void handle_read(error_code error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        if (!error) {
            res_ = {http::status::ok, 11,
                    boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(req_)};
            res_.keep_alive(false);
            res_.prepare_payload();

            http::async_write(socket_, res_,
                              boost::bind(&session::handle_write,
                                          shared_from_this(),
                                          asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }

    void handle_write(error_code error) {
        if (!error) {
            do_receive();
        }
    }

  private:
    ssl_socket socket_;

    beast::flat_buffer                buf_;
    http::request<http::string_body>  req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;
};

struct server {
    server(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port)
        : acceptor_(ex, {tcp::v4(), port})
        , context_(Ctx::sslv23) //
    {
        acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        context_.set_options(Ctx::default_workarounds | Ctx::no_sslv2 |
                             Ctx::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(&server::get_password);
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("cert.pem");
        context_.use_private_key_file("key.pem", Ctx::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        start_accept();
    }

  private:
    using Ctx = ssl::context;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    Ctx           context_;

    static std::string get_password(size_t, Ctx::password_purpose) {
        return "test";
    }

    void start_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            // make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()), // for multi-threaded servers
            [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "accept good" << std::endl;
                    auto sess = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(s),
                                                          context_);
                    sess->start();
                }

                start_accept();
            });
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    server s(ioc.get_executor(), 8989);

    ioc.run_for(30s);
}
```

### UPDATE

Saving information from the comments for the future:

[Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aced0bfed647f683) my review of your code, same but 100 lines of code less.

Adding back 50 lines I implemented the minimal CONNECT parsing and connect code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28fbdaf23ab00586 - See it working with

```
  curl -px http://localhost:8989
```

on my system, for both HTTP and HTTPS targets:

[image]

### Listing: Full HTTTP CONNECT de,p supporting any protocol (HTTPS included)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace Tcp {
    namespace asio    = boost::asio;
    namespace ph      = asio::placeholders;
    using tcp         = asio::ip::tcp;
    using socket_type = tcp::socket;
    using error_code  = boost::system::error_code;

    template <typename Session> struct Listener {
        Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t bind_port)
            : acceptor_(ex, tcp::endpoint({}, bind_port)) {}

        void do_accept() {
            acceptor_.async_accept( //
                make_strand(acceptor_.get_executor()), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                    std::cerr << "accepted " << s.remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                    if (!ec) {
                        std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s))->start();
                        do_accept();
                    } else {
                        std::cerr << "do_accept: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
        }

      private:
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    };

    namespace util {
        // Relay from from_ to to_ sockets
        // Lifetime shared with shared owner
        struct half_duplex {
            using Owner = std::weak_ptr<void>;
            half_duplex(socket_type& f, socket_type& t) : from_(f), to_(t) {}

            void start(Owner w) {
                owner_ = w;
                do_read();
            }

            // send previously received pending data first
            template <typename ConstBufferSequence> void start(Owner w, ConstBufferSequence pending) {
                owner_ = w;
                async_write(to_, pending, boost::bind(&half_duplex::on_written, owner_shared(), ph::error));
            }

          private:
            socket_type& from_;
            socket_type& to_;
            Owner        owner_;
            std::array<uint8_t, 8192> buf_;

            void do_read() {
                from_.async_read_some(
                    asio::buffer(buf_),
                    boost::bind(&half_duplex::on_read, owner_shared(), ph::error, ph::bytes_transferred));
            }
            void on_read(error_code ec, size_t xfer) {
                if (!ec)
                    async_write(to_, asio::buffer(buf_, xfer),
                                boost::bind(&half_duplex::on_written, owner_shared(), ph::error));
            }
            void on_written(error_code ec) {
                if (!ec)
                    do_read();
            }
            std::shared_ptr<half_duplex> owner_shared() {
                if (auto o = owner_.lock())
                    return std::shared_ptr<half_duplex>(o, this); // aliasing constructor
                else
                    throw std::bad_weak_ptr();
            }
        };
    } // namespace util

    namespace proxy {
        namespace http = boost::beast::http;

        struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
            Session(socket_type s) : client_(std::move(s)), server_(s.get_executor()) {}

            void start() {
                http::async_read(
                    client_, lead_in_, req_,
                    boost::bind(&Session::on_connect_request, shared_from_this(), ph::error));
            }

          private:
            asio::streambuf                  lead_in_;
            http::request<http::empty_body>  req_;
            http::response<http::empty_body> res_;

            socket_type client_, server_;
            util::half_duplex down_stream_{server_, client_};
            util::half_duplex up_stream_{client_, server_};

            void on_connect_request(error_code ec) {
                if (ec.failed() || req_.method() != http::verb::connect)
                    return; // TODO error handling

                std::cerr << "Connect request: " << req_ << std::endl;

                // TODO handle headers?
                std::string upstream(req_.target());

                auto pos  = upstream.find_last_of(":");
                auto host = upstream.substr(0, pos);
                auto svc  = upstream.substr(pos + 1);
                if (svc.empty())
                    svc = "http";

                // TODO async resolve?
                auto eps = tcp::resolver(server_.get_executor()).resolve(host, svc);

                asio::async_connect(server_, eps,
                                    boost::bind(&Session::on_connect, shared_from_this(), ph::error));
            }

            void on_connect(error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return; // TODO error handling
                std::cerr << "Connected to " << server_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

                res_ = {http::status::ok, req_.version()};
                res_.keep_alive(true);
                res_.prepare_payload();
                http::async_write(client_, res_,
                                  boost::bind(&Session::on_connect_response, shared_from_this(), ph::error));
            }

            void on_connect_response(error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return; // TODO error handling

                up_stream_.start(shared_from_this());
                if (lead_in_.size())
                    down_stream_.start(shared_from_this(), lead_in_.data());
                else
                    down_stream_.start(shared_from_this());
            }
        };
    }

    using Proxy = Listener<proxy::Session>;
} // namespace Tcp

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << std::quoted(argv[0]) << " <bind port>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto bind_port = static_cast<uint16_t>(::atoi(argv[1]));

    try {
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;

        Tcp::Proxy p(ioc.get_executor(), bind_port);
        p.do_accept();

        ioc.run();
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "main: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250921/discussion-on-answer-by-sehe-boost-asio-openssl-https-proxy-request-handshake-fa).