# difference between `delete this` and `this->~Obj` in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, assignment-operator, delete-operator, double-free

When I am writing a demo string class, in the copy assignment function, I try to clear itself through 'delete this' before copy.But it failed.

```cpp
    Str &operator=(const Str &s) {
        if (this != &s) {  // self-assignment check
            //delete this; //cannot run as I imagine
            this->~Str();  
            _size = s._size;
            _str = new char[_size + 1];
            memcpy(_str, s._str, _size + 1);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~Str() {
        _size = 0;
        delete[] _str;
    }
```

the linux told me

> double free or corruption (out)
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `delete this` calls `this->~Obj();` and `free(this)`. One deletes objects via `delete` when they were created via `new`. While `this->~Obj();` manually calls destructor, to be used with placement new.

Comment: `delete this` runs the destructor *and* frees whatever memory your object was given. Just write a separate "dealloc" function and call that instead of playing tricks with the destructor.

Comment: [Is "delete this" allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150942/is-delete-this-allowed-in-c) is worth a read.

Comment: @ALX23z Not `free(this);`, but `operator delete(this);`.

Comment: Please also read: [What is The Rule of Three?](/questions/4172722)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`delete x;` is equivalent to `x->~T();` followed by `operator delete(x)` (which is similar to `free(x)`, but might be incompatible with it).

`x->~T();` is a dangerous tool. In this case it must be followed by `new(this) T(...);` (placement-new) to call a constructor, otherwise the current object is considered to be "dead", and any interaction with it causes undefined behavior.

But even if you do call placement-new, it can throw. Then the object remains dead, and the caller gets UB when it tries to destroy the already dead object again.

Conclusion: `x->~T();` is hard to use correctly, use something else.

- Either write a function that does the same thing as the destrutor, and call it instead. Unlike the destructor, the object wouldn't be considered dead after calling it, so no placement-new is needed.
- Or use the copy&swap idiom. Write the assignment as:

  ```
  Str &operator=(Str s) noexcept
  {
      std::swap(_str, s._str);
      std::swap(_size, s._size);
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  This is an universal way of writing assignments. It works both as copy and move assignment, is exception-safe, etc.

Comment: the most sensible use of `x->~T();` is if you created the object with placement-new, I think.

Comment: @user253751 Mhm, I only meant that it's unsuitable for this usecase.

Comment: Another trap with `x->~T()` followed by placement new is that if the original type of the object that `x` points at was a type `U` that's derived from `T` the result will be a non-viable hybrid that's neither a `T` nor a `U`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete this` already executes `this->~Str()` but that's only one problem. After `delete this` you call `_size = s._size` which is actually `this->_size = s._size`. But lifetime of `this` already ended so any call to `this` can lead to undefined behavior. So not `delete this` nor `this->~Str()` belong to your assign operator.

Comment: @Retired Ninja good point.