# Releasing memory of std::function inside the function body

Tags: c++, c++17, delete-operator, std-function, self-destruction

I need to pass a `std::function` as a `void*` pointer to be executed asynchronously, so I create a `std::function` on the heap. Is it safe to delete the `std::function` object from inside the function body?

Please see the following example:

```
using T = std::function<void()>;

void fun(int data)
{
    T* t = new T([&t, data]()
    {
        //do something
        delete t;
    }

    ExecuteAsync(t);
}
```

Comment: Safe as long as you don't do anything in the lambda after `delete`. This is similar to [Is "delete this" allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3150942/2752075).

Comment: Isn't `&t` going to capture `t` by reference though, i.e. ending up with a dangling reference after `fun` returns?

Comment: This is poor design. You are creating a tight coupling between the subroutine and how it’s memory allocation is handled.

Comment: Why is `ExecuteAsync` taking a `std::function<void()>*`?

Comment: `to pass a std::function as a void pointer` Are you _absolutely sure_ the `ExecuteAsync` function expects a _pointer_ to exactly `std::function<void()>`? That is very odd. Who wrote the function? Are you _sure_ the function doesn't take a `void (*)()` pointer? What is the _exact full actual_ declaration of `ExecuteAsync` function?

Comment: ```ExecuteAsync``` that's a legacy code which I can't modify, it uses a void* type: ```void ExecuteAsync(void* fun)```

Comment: @Irbis And what does `ExecuteAsync` assume the type of `fun` actually is? You cannot call a `void*` pointer, there's no `operator()` for. Thus `ExecuteAsync` needs to cast the function argument to something meaningful – but to *what* exactly? I'd consider it pretty unlikely it would cast it to a `std::function` pointer, and if it doesn't, you end up in undefined behaviour for casting to the bad type inside `ExecuteAsync`!

Answer (score 1):

#### Mistake in capturing `&t`

Firstly, note that capturing `[&t]` is a mistake. `&t` would dangle when `fun` returns.
Either you'd need to allocate the `std::function` first, or you'd need to use C++23 explicit object member functions to make this work:

```cpp
// C++17
auto* t = new std::function<void()>;
*t = [t, data] { /* do something */; delete t; };

// C++23
auto* t = new std::function<void()>([data](this auto&& self) {
    // do something
    delete &self;
};
```

Assuming you did one of these two things ...

#### Delete self in `std::function`

Pedantically speaking, it is not safe to do. [[func.wrap.func] `operator()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func#lib:function,invocation) is only said to return `INVOKE<R>(...)`, but it's not guaranteed to consist of just a `return` statement that does that.
Hypothetically, it would be allowed to implement it like<sup>(1)</sup>:

```cpp
R operator()(ArgTypes... args) const {
    R result = INVOKE<R>(f, std​::​forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
    // read members of this object
    return result;
}
```

Reading the memory of an object whose lifetime has ended is obviously UB, so this would break your code.
However, no standard library does this, and there is no obvious reason why anyone would.

In practice, what you're doing will work, for the same reason that `delete this` is allowed. See [Is "delete this" allowed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3150942/5740428).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> A [*Returns* paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/library#structure.specifications-3.8) only states the returned value. It does not impose further requirements on the implementation.

#### Further notes on design

However, if you have to ask yourself, maybe it's not a good idea from a code style perspective.
If you instead did:

```cpp
ExecuteAsync(std::move(my_function));
```

... where `ExecuteAsync` obtains ownership of a `std::function` and also destroys it once executed, it would be much more obvious how and why it's correct.
At the very least, you could hand `ExecuteAsync` a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Normally I would use move semantics as you have mentioned but that is a quite specific case. I work with a legacy code and ```ExecuteAsync``` is defined this way: ```void ExecuteAsync(void* fun)```

Comment: @Irbis so `ExecuteAsync` then casts `void* fun` to `std::function<void()>*` or what's going on? This is pretty bizarre.

Comment: Yes, maybe I have made a mistake that I have generalized the example, but the real use case is to pass ```std::function<void()>*``` using winapi ```PostMessage LPARAM```. When the message is processed the ```std::function<void()>*```is cast this way:
```T* t = (T*)(msg.lParam)```

Comment: @Irbis you can probably work with function pointer instead, and use `int data` as the LPARAM data instead of `std::function`. That's closer to how the WinAPI is expected to be used, I imagine.