# What is stack based class?

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent an object being created on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985/how-to-prevent-an-object-being-created-on-the-heap)

Hi,

I heard a concept called as stack based class. I.e. we can’t create instance of the class using new.

I am hearing this for the first time. One way to implement this by private overloading of  ‘new ’ operator.

If anybody know details about the stack based class please inform me.

Answer (score 3):

It's all in the instantiation:

```
AnotherClass::SomeMethod(...) {
  MyClass stackBased;
  MyClass *heapBased;

  *heapBased = new MyClass();
  *heapBased->DoSomething();
  delete heapBased;

  stackBased.DoSomething();

  ...
}
```

A stackbased class is automatically allocated, instantiated and deallocated on the stack, whereas you need to do it all by yourself for a heapbased.

Comment: That's not the question. The question is, how would you stop your code snippet from compiling? What do you do to `MyClass` such that "we can’t create instance of the class using new" (to quote the question above).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. But in that case then this question is a possible duplicate as KennyTM noted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overloading new operator follow the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

- A static method to create new instances of this class.
- An access method to get the last instance (from the top of stack)

Comment: I've been hearing a lot about using factories instead of overloading "new" recently... why is this?

Comment: ''An access method to get the last instance (from the top of stack)'' ---- ??? Can you explain this more detailed?